# Apply matrix operation to every k-dim row in an n-dim matrix

Tags: multidimensional-array, matrix, function-pointers, octave, matrix-multiplication

Does octave have a method by which you can take a function which applies to every column in a 2-dimensional matrix and convert it into a function which applies to every line along the kth dimension in an n-dimensional matrix?

As an example, here I have a function which scales every column in a matrix so that the minimum value is zero and the maximum is one:

```
function [res] = normalizeColRange(m)
    nrows = size(m,1);

    maxes = max(m,[],1);
    mins = min(m,[],1);

    res = [speye(nrows), -ones(nrows,1)] * [m; mins] / diag(maxes - mins);
endfunction
```

Now I'm looking for a function (I'll call it operateDim) so that if I want to scale every dim-3 line in a 4-dimensional matrix (m) the same way, I can say:

```
res = operateDim(@normalizeColRange,m,3);
```

and get back a 4-dimensional matrix of the same size, where all the entries have been scaled along dimension 3.  In other words:

```
min(res,[],3) == 0
```

and

```
max(res,[],3) == 1
```

A simpler such input function is simply matrix multiplication.  ie:

```
res = operateDim(@(M) A * M, m, 3)
```

would treat each d-3 line of m as a column in a matrix and multiply A by that column appropriately so that

```
reshape(permute(res,[3,1,2,4]),size(res,3),[]) ==
A * reshape(permute(m,[3,1,2,4]),size(m,3),[])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at creating operateDim.  It seems somewhat verbose and I wonder if it fits into a more general paradigm or if such a function already exists in the octave library:

```
function [res] = operateDim(f,m,d):
    p = 1:ndims(m);
    p([1,d]) = [d,1];
    m = permute(m, p);
    nsizes = size(m);
    m = reshape(m, nsizes(1), []);
    res = f(m);
    assert(ndims(res) <= 2);
    nsizes(1) = size(res,1);
    assert(size(res,2) == size(m,2));
    res = reshape(res, nsizes);
    res = permute(res, p);
endfunction
```